# SSL and mod_rewrite error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have https on my site. 
Pages with rewritten URL in my site are inaccessible while direct urls (folders).

here's the htaccess

```
## 2009-12-17 16:52 JGC [START]
## Enable http compression for this site
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  ## Directive "DeflateCompressionLevel" not allowed in .htaccess, only valid in server config and virtual hosts
  # DeflateCompressionLevel 9
  # file-types indicated will not be compressed
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:swf|flv|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|gz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
## 2009-12-17 16:52 JGC [END]

## 2010-03-05 16:05 JGC [START]
#<IfModule mod_alias.c>
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/)$ /online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/en)$ /en/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/en/)$ /en/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/en\.html)$ /en/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/sc)$ /sc/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/sc/)$ /sc/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/sc\.html)$ /sc/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/ch)$ /ch/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/ch/)$ /ch/online-casino-poker-register.html
#RedirectMatch 301 ^(/ch\.html)$ /ch/online-casino-poker-register.html
#</IfModule>
## 2010-03-05 16:05 JGC [END]

##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 10492 2008-07-02 06:38:28Z ircmaxell $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##


#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteLog "/var/www/html/dafa888/rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !jfcookie\[lang\] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh-cn [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /sc/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !jfcookie\[lang\] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh-tw [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /ch/ [L,R=301]


#RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !jfcookie[lang] [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} jfcookie\[lang\] [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} jfcookie\[lang\]=([^;]+) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [NC,QSA]


########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301]
########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]


#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand the issue, but you can enable debug logging so you can see exactly what is happening. Add the lines

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 3
```